# How do I retrieved appended values from a separate Select lists using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, append

I have script that will append hidden values to pass to a form. When I post the form only the first list value gets passed. I believe i need to somehow make the Second list unique name.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Color').change(function() {
$('.inputs').html('');
var $explodedVal = $(this).val().split('-');
$('.inputs').append('<input type="hidden" name="caseOpt" id="caseOpt"  value="' + $explodedVal[1]+'">');
});
});
</script>
```

Here is the First List.

```
<label>Color</label>
<br>
<select name="Color" class="listOpt" id="Color" title="Color" >
<option value="None-0">Select Ring Size</option>
<option value="Red-1">Red</option>
<option value="Blue-2">Blue</option
</select>



<script>
$(function() {
$('#Size').change(function() {
$('.inputs').html('');
var $explodedVal2 = $(this).val().split('-');
var $explodedVal3 = $(this).val().split('-');

$('.inputs').append('<input type="hidden" name="colorOpt" id="colorOpt"  value="' + $explodedVal2[1]+'">');
$('.inputs').append('<input type="hidden" name="colorInc" id="colorInc" value="' + $explodedVal3[0]+'">');
});
});</script>
```

Here is the Second List

```
<label>Size</label>
<br>
<select name="Size" class="listOpt" id="Size" title="Size" >
<option value="None-0">Select Ring Size</option>
<option value="Large-1">Large</option>
<option value="Xlarge-2">Xlarge</option
</select>
```

Comment: sorry for posting a non-useful comment but URGHHH on that java tag..

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use values like "None-0"? Shouldn't "0" be fine?

You can have an object like:

```
var data = {
    color: null,
    size: null
};
```

and then acces the properties using:

```
data[color] = 0;
data[size] = 1;
```

In your case:

```
<label>Color</label>
<br>
<select name="Color" class="listOpt" id="Color" title="Color" >
    <option value="0">Select Ring Size</option>
    <option value="1">Red</option>
    <option value="2">Blue</option
</select>

<label>Size</label>
<br>
<select name="Size" class="listOpt" id="Size" title="Size" >
    <option value="0">Select Ring Size</option>
    <option value="1">Large</option>
    <option value="2">Xlarge</option
</select>       

<script>
    var data = {
        color: null,
        size: null
    };

    $(function() {
        $('#Size').change(function() {
            data[size] = $(this).val();
        });
        $('#Color').change(function() {
            data[color] = $(this).val();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well i am storing two seperate values in the options list. Ignore the None-0 that was error. That way i can use the jQuery split feature to extract two values on separate hidden fields.